# Which version of windows 7 should I choose to install

Tags: windows-7, installation, 32bit-64bit

I want to install Windows 7 on my system. But I am not sure which version should I choose to install.
Shall I go for 32 bit or 64? How can I decide that? If I can install any of them then which version should I choose (I am a software developer and I will install various development software)

Below are my hardware configuration, I ain't sure that is required or not to decide the version because I am complete stupe when it comes to OS.

- **Processor Name**: Intel Core 2 Duo E7500 @2.93 GHz
- **Max TPD**: 65W
- **Memory Type**: DDR2
- **Size**: 4096 Mbytes

Please let me know if I need to provide other information also.

Comment: Also, if you don't need to bind to a domain home premium is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick 64Bit to use all the  RAM available.  Youu would likley access about 3.5GB with 32Bit and 64 should `see`4GB less any used for video or other system needs. However, assure that you have any needed 64 bit drivers and that all software runs on the 64bit OS.  No reason not to go 64 bit unless driver or compatability issues exist.